# This query doesn't give me the expected results?

Tags: mysql

I have been trying all night to make it work, but it doesn't. When I give the date ranges for `adate` as 2014-03-12 it even shows me the data of previous dates. What am I missing here?

```
SELECT tno, type, ccno, paidamt, aby, adate, atime 
FROM payment 
WHERE 
    adate<='2014-03-12' 
    AND adate<='2014-03-12' 
    AND aby='anuradha' 
    AND type='ADD' OR type='REM' 
    AND delstat='0'
```

Comment: What kind of field is `adate` set to? It should be a `DATE` or `DATETIME` field, and if the data in the field is not stored in the same format `YYYY-MM-DD`, you should wrap `adate` in the `DATE()` function: `WHERE DATE(adate) <= '2014-03-12'`. P.s. your first two `WHERE` conditions are identical.

Comment: What data you have and what are you expecting? Show sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets

```
SELECT tno, type, ccno, paidamt, aby, adate, atime 
FROM payment 
WHERE 
    adate<='2014-03-12' 
    AND adate<='2014-03-12' 
    AND aby='anuradha' 
    AND (type='ADD' OR type='REM' )
    AND delstat='0'
```

Also adate is specified twice. You should probably remove the second one

```
SELECT tno, type, ccno, paidamt, aby, adate, atime 
FROM payment 
WHERE 
    adate>='2014-03-12' 
    AND adate<='2014-03-12' 
    AND aby='anuradha' 
    AND type='ADD' OR type='REM' 
    AND delstat='0'
```

Comment: I assume one of the a dates is supposed to be greater than it equal instead of both less than ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your problem is related with that `OR`. Enclose it in parenthesis:

```
SELECT tno, type, ccno, paidamt, aby, adate, atime 
FROM payment 
WHERE 
    adate<='2014-03-12' 
    AND adate<='2014-03-12' 
    AND aby='anuradha' 
    AND (type='ADD' OR type='REM' )
    AND delstat='0'
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you have a typo in

```
  adate<='2014-03-12' 
  AND adate<='2014-03-12'
```

This date-range part of the query is asking, umm, twice, for all rows on or before 12-Mar-2014. That might not be what you want.

Do you want this?

```
  adate >=  '2014-03-12'
  AND adate < '2014-03-12' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That particular pair of inequalities is the most reliable way to get rows occurring on a particular day.

Also you may want to replace

```
AND type='ADD' OR type='REM'
```

with

```
AND type IN ('ADD', 'REM')
```

because it will likely perform better and get you out of trying to guess the associativity of `AND` and `OR` (which I believe you guessed wrong).

Answer (score 1):

> *when I give the date ranges for adate as 2014-03-12 it even shows me the data of previous dates... What Am I missing here?*

Input to `adate` was wrong. You should have used different value when said a *range*, but you are not doing that and you are comparing for a date before of that. And hence previous date results.

Try this way:

```
set @startDate = '2014-03-01';  -- as an example
set @endDate = '2014-03-12';  

SELECT tno, type, ccno, paidamt, aby, adate, atime 
FROM payment 
WHERE 
    adate between @startDate and @endDate
    AND aby='anuradha' 
    AND type in ('ADD', 'REM') 
    AND delstat='0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adate<='2014-03-12' AND adate<='2014-03-12'
```

seems like a pretty useless duplication of a condition here.

Next, as your statement is formulated now, due to precedence of logical operators, it's evaluated as

```
( adate<='2014-03-12' AND adate<='2014-03-12' AND aby='anuradha' AND type='ADD')
OR 
(type='REM' AND delstat='0')
```

which is probably not what you want, and explains why earlier dates seep through (through the right side of the OR condition.

A rather complete overview of operator precedence in SQL can be found here: [SQL 'AND' or 'OR' comes first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418547/sql-and-or-or-comes-first?lq=1) and here: [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)